# How to convert vent-free LP heater/fireplace to NG

Tags: fireplace

I have a Jøtul #3 Classic vent free free-standing heater (looks like an old school wood burning stove) that was manufactured to use LP……but I have a natural gas hookup in my fireplace. Can anyone tell me if it’s possible to convert it from a propane unit to one that uses natural gas?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Jotul or a local LP/NG store should know and/or have a conversion kit.  Usually only a nozzel that needs changing.  Due to the possible danger of CO gas or fire, the local pros should help.

Comment: This seems very much like a shopping question, which is explicitly off-topic. A kit available today may not be available next week.

Answer (score 0):

Do an on-line search for Jotul. They are still in business but that #3 has been discontinued. On their website you can find the name and information of a dealer in your area.